# Why does find_all give an error even though there is no error in just find? (Python Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get the titles of songs from Billboard top 100.
The picture is their html script.
[image: HTML of site]

I wrote this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url= 'http://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/2015/hot-100-songs'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
songtitle = soup.find("div", {"class": "row-title"}).h2.contents
print(songtitle)
```

It retrieves the first title "UPTOWN FUNK!"
When I use `find_all` it gives me the error:

```
line 6, in <module>
songtitle = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row-title"}).h2.contents
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'h2'
```

Why does it give me an error instead of giving me all the titles? The full html script can be found by using Control Shift J in chrome on this site: http://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/2015/hot-100-songs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns a `ResultSet` object which is basically a list of `Tag` instances - it does not have a `find()` method. You need to loop over the results of `find_all()` and call `find()` on each tag:

```
for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row-title"}):
    songtitle = item.h2.contents
    print(songtitle)
```

Or, make a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for title in soup.select("div.row-title h2"):
    print(title.get_text())
```

By the way, this problem is [covered in the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This
>   usually happens because you expected `find_all()` to return a single tag
>   or string. But `find_all()` returns a *list* of tags and strings–a
>   `ResultSet` object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the
>   `.foo` of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to
>   use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns a list always. You can do list operations.

For example,

```
songtitle = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row-title"})[0].get
print songtitle.get('h2')
songtitle = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row-title"})[1].get
print songtitle.get('h2')
```

Output:

> ```
> UPTOWN FUNK!
> THINKING OUT LOUD
> ```

```
for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row-title"}):
    songtitle=item.get('h2')
    print songtitle
```